# How to apply Shamir's Secret Sharing on strings passwords

Tags: c++11, encryption, cryptography, passwords, secret-key

I was trying to write a simple code to generate and obtain passwords using Shamir's secret sharing method.
My question is:

How can I apply this to string passwords that are not just numbers like
1523?

I have seen a lot of examples of this Shamir's secret sharing method but all of them uses numbers and modules. But if I have a password in string format like password1234, I can't apply this method because of the size of this password in bytes. And I can't use module because I would not be able to recover the original password. Any idea?

Comment: This can be solved using [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), in which the "public key" system is Shamir secret sharing.

Comment: Passwords are stored in bytes like any data in computers, that can be easily stored into integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string -> bytes -> decimal and and get the shares in decimal format. If you combine the shares to recover the original password you sould convert the result vice versa: decimal -> bytes -> string